# How can a ssl client accept an expired SSL certificate

Tags: java, c, sockets, ssl, client-server

I have a unique problem here-
The server is under our control and has already been updated with a new server certificate that is about to expire soon.

But the nature of our clients is such that updating the SSL certificates would require manual intervention to setup certain aspects for them to be up and running after that. We do not have enough time to make change and get all clients running before the certificate expires.

We are using one-way SSL i.e. only the client is validating the server certificate (TCP communication).

So my question is- Is there any way to force the client to accept the certificate beyond the expiration date so we get more time to update them all? We can make any changes on the server in the meanwhile but cannot touch the clients.

I ran a wireshark trace today setting the system date to beyond the certificate expiry on both the client and server, its the client that is throwing certificate_expired I believe in this case since the server already has the new server side certificate installed.
The communication doesn't even get to SSL/TLS messages by the looks of it, i.e. it fails before that.

The client is written in C and uses OpenSSL for establishing SSL connections and the server is written in Java.

I have tried using all sort of TrustManagers to accept everything on the server-side but the problem is the client it seems. The information being transmitted is not sensitive and if there is any way to do so, we can disable all SSL functionality to make it work, but again whatever we can do has to be done without touching the client.

Let me know if further details are required to make the situation more clear. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: no. you can't force it, unless you have control over the clients - which you've already said you don't. If a server could FORCE a client to accept an expired cert, then the server could also force a client to accept an invalid/fake certificate as well. In other words, what you want would UTTERLY negate the entire purpose of ssl.

Comment: Makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say so, but it sounds like you are using "self-signed" certs and that you are concerned about the time to go around the network and add the server's cert to the cert store on each machine. Assuming that is the scenario -- you have a **very simple** solution...just switch to a commercial cert. Comodo runs deals all the time, and you can typically get a year for under $100. They even offer free 30-day trials. https://ssl.comodo.com/